# Login to Steamaccount secured with SteamGuard via CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, steam

i want to login to my Steamaccount using the Steam CLI provided by Valve:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Command-Line_Parameters_4

normally i would use the login command: -login <[username]|anonymous> [password]

But this doesn't work when the account you want to log in to is Steam Guard secured. Because this forces you into a new window where you have to input your SteamGuardCode.

Is there any possible workaround so i can pass the SteamGuardCode to Steam while i run the initial login Command?

I've already tried passing the code after and instead of the Password. But both didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an option `set_steam_guard_code` in the link you provided.
Additionally you can use https://github.com/dyc3/steamguard-cli to get the code without a phone, but some people will say that it defeats the purpose of 2FA, I'm not a security expert.
So the command would be something like this

```
steamcmd.exe set_steam_guard_code 012345 login password
```

or you can use steamcmd command:

```
login   [<password>|anonymous] [<Steam guard code>] Login to Steam
```

Comment: Steam probably added this feature after you've asked the question, but maybe someone will be looking for the answer